# public static function vs static function in php

Tags: php, static, public

Is there any reason to write `public static function` instead of just `static function`? It's still accessible via class name like Class::staticMethod() isn't?

Comment: Its explicit. Static only implys publicClass methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.

Answer (score 3):

Public is implicit (used if not declared otherwise), so it will work either way.

The point of writing `public` is to make your code cleaner, easier to read.

E.g. in java, the default visibility is not public, so when a java programmer reads your php, he'll wonder where the heck it is accessible from. Declaring it `public` saves some headache.

Comment: I see, thanks. Will use public.